# multiprocessing.Processのtarget内でsignalをhandleできない

Tags: windows, python3, selenium-webdriver

multiprocessing.Processでtarget関数(引数`target`として渡す関数)のなかでSIGTERMをハンドルしたいのですがうまくいきません
どうすればいいのでしょうか?

GUIを使ったプログラムでStartボタンを押すと別プロセスで`test_main`関数が動きます
Stopボタンを押すとStartボタンを押したときに起動したプロセスにSIGTERMが送られます
しかし、test_main内ではWebdriverが動いており、このWebdriverを片付けてから(driver.quit()してから)プロセスを終了させたいです。

そこでtest_main内でsignal.signalを設定してSIGTERMを受け取ったらwebdriverを片付けた後でプロセスを終了させたいのですがStopボタンを押してSIGTERMを送ってもうまくいきません

```
import tkinter as tk
from multiprocessing import Process
from tkinter import messagebox
import sys
import signal
import time
import os
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


def create_driver():
    options = Options()
    if sys.platform == "darwin":
        options.binary_location = '/Applications/Google Chrome Canary.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome Canary'
    #options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
    if sys.platform == "win32":
        options.binary_location = "C:\\(user_home)\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome SxS\\Application\\chrome.exe" #location of chrome canary for windows
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    #options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
    options.add_argument('--reduce-security-for-testing')
    options.add_argument('--allow-insecure-localhost')
    if sys.platform == "win32":
        chromedriver_path = r".\chromedriver"
    else:
        chromedriver_path = "./chromedriver"

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver_path, chrome_options=options)
    return driver



class GUI(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.cur_process = None
        self.pack()
        self.create_widget()

    def create_widget(self):
        self.start = tk.Button(self, width=5, padx=10, pady=3)
        self.start["text"] = "Start"
        self.start["command"] = self.start_event
        self.start.grid(row=2, column=2, columnspan=2, padx=4, pady=10)
        self.quit = tk.Button(self, width=5, padx=10, pady=3)
        self.quit["text"] = "Stop"
        self.quit["command"] = self.stop_event
        self.quit.grid(row=3, column=2, columnspan=2, padx=4, pady=10)

    def start_event(self):
        if self.cur_process is None:
            self.cur_process = Process(target=test_main) #target function
            self.cur_process.start()

    def stop_event(self):
        if self.cur_process != None:
            os.kill(self.cur_process.pid, signal.SIGTERM)
#            self.driver.quit()
            self.cur_process = None


def test_main(): #target function
    # set signal handler to SIGTERM
    def k():
        print("set new signal handler")
        try:
            driver.quit()
            # then terminate process
        except NameError:# driver is not defined
            pass # do nothing
        sys.exit() # terminate process
    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, k)
    # do something with driver
    driver = create_driver()
def gui():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("400x300")
    g = GUI(master=root)
    g.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    gui()
```

Answer (score 0):

もしかしたら見当違いの回答になってしまうかもしれませんが、自分でSIGTERMを捕まえてワーカープロセスの掃除をするよりは、ワーカープロセスを daemonモードで動かしてしまうのはどうでしょうか。

http://ja.pymotw.com/2/multiprocessing/basics.html#id3

daemonモードで動かすとそのワーカープロセスはメインのプログラムが終了するとその直前に、自動的に終了してくれるようです。

追記: 質問文を良くみたら「ストップボタン=プログラム終了」ではないので、この回答は妥当ではないですね。すいません。

Answer (score 0):

Windows限定ですが、/fの強制終了と/tの子プロセス含むのオプションを付けて、taskkillコマンドを実行するのが良いかもしれません。
[release Selenium chromedriver.exe from memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21320837/release-selenium-chromedriver-exe-from-memory)
[Is it possible to kill a process on Windows from within Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278847/is-it-possible-to-kill-a-process-on-windows-from-within-python)

あるいは、アプリで作った自分の子プロセスとseleniumで作ったWebDriverの子プロセスの両方を別々に終了させる必要があるのかもしれません。

なお、必要ならばrunasで管理者権限にて実行することもできるはずです。
[Set administrator privileges to subprocess.check_call() in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20505893/set-administrator-privileges-to-subprocess-check-call-in-python)
[Request UAC elevation from within a Python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130763/request-uac-elevation-from-within-a-python-script)
[Run .exe file via Python as Administrator](https://superuser.com/questions/615654/run-exe-file-via-python-as-administrator)